# Pre and post build steps in nx.dev

Tags: javascript, nx.dev

I'm using **nx.dev** to build and test a web application.
The `workspace.json` contains the scripts to build and test the app, however the build phase still need a pre processing of some files.

Is there any way of adding a pre build step (i.e. specify an external bash script or JavaScript code)?

The online documentation doesn't mention that 
https://nx.dev/react/cli/build

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There isn't an option to run shell scripts in the `build` builder itself, but you can use `@nrwl/workspace:run-commands` builder to do that.

In your `workspace.json` you should add to the `architect` section of the project in question.

```
"architect": {
  "prepare": {
    "builder": "@nrwl/workspace:run-commands",
    "options": {
      "commands": [
        {
          "command": "echo Hello!"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I named the target `prepare` but you can choose any name you want. And then you can execute it with `nx prepare [projectName]`.

You can use `run-commands` to compose existing targets like `build` and `test` with arbitrary shell commands to form  new targets. It's up to you how you want to wire things up.

I put together an example repo here to give you some ideas: https://github.com/jaysoo/nx-run-commands-example

Comment: For anyone confused about the property keys nomenclature (architect, builder), read this line from the nx docs: "Note: There are a few property keys in workspace.json that have interchangeable aliases. You can replace *generators* with *schematics*, *targets* with *architect* or *executor* with *builder*." (https://nx.dev/latest/angular/executors/using-builders#executor-definitions)

Comment: This is all nice and thanks, but it doesn't answer on the 'post' part. If I understand correctly this doesn't assist in creating automation 'tasks' (abstractly speaking) that will run following a 'build' target run.

Comment: You can currently create a 'dependsOn' key with an array of targets which should be run 'BEFORE' the current target. 

So the npm 'pre-' part is already covered. 
Only the 'post-' script part is not covered, which is sad. 

see here: https://nx.dev/l/a/core-concepts/configuration
and scroll to 'Target Dependencies'